# play wav file in server when file is in different directory

Tags: php, html, webserver

i'm trying to make an web site where the user can listen to different wav files. 
I made a `php` script to get all `.wav` files that i want and i keep their path on an array.

Then im doing this to play the audio:

```
echo "<a href='teste.wav'>Play sample 1 </a>";
echo "<a href='" .$audios[$id][1] ."'>Play sample 2 </a>";
?>
<script src="http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/js></script>
```

On the first case i got the audio on same folder as the script and it works fine. On  the second case i have it in a completely different directory and it never finds the file.
I know that the sample 2 will ref to something directly under the current directory where the script is being executed, but i tried to make the `$audios[$id][1]` like `http://home/.../file.wav` and still doesn't work.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please give us a sample of the content of `$audios` ?

Comment: this is what i get:
index : -1458206716

$audio[$id][0] is  /home/jorge/VOCE/Recordings/-1458206716/Tiago@Aug_31_2012_Tiago_ID_1204811836_prebaseline.wav

$audio[$id][1] is
/home/jorge/VOCE/Recordings/-1458206716/Tiago@Jul_17_2012_Mariana_ID_-1458206716_baseline.wav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/home/jorge/VOCE/Recordings/-1458206716/Tiago@Aug_31_2012_Tiago_ID_1204811836_pr‌​ebaseline.wav
```

Do not use absolute paths. These are **invalid** outside your local file system. You have to use relative paths so browser can build request pointing to reachable file, so it should be more like this:

```
VOCE/Recordings/-1458206716/Tiago@Aug_31_2012_Tiago_ID_1204811836_pr‌​ebaseline.wav
```

(assuming your project publicly visible folders is parent to `VOCE`)

> but i tried to make the $audios[$id][1] like `http://home/.../file.wav`
>   and still doesnt work.

That would work **ONLY** if your browser is running physically on the same machine your server is running and filesystem is accessible to you.

**EDIT**

How to do this right - some assumptions (if real system differs, just make adjustments) Your filesystem structure is as follow

```
  document-root/
     scripts/
        test.php
     recordings/
        audio.wav
     index.html
```

`document-root` is location on your disk which your httpd serves all files from. It is irrelevant what it really is. If I do `http://yourdomain/index.html` then it shall show content of `index.html`. Your scripts are in `scripts/` folder and your audio files are in `recordings`. Then **relative path** from `test.php` to `audio.wav` is `../recordings/audio.wav`. If you really need to use **absolute path** (not recommended) then it shall be `http://yourdomain/recordings/audio.wav`. Choose what's simpliest for you.

Comment: The problem is that there are no directories related, im testing this on my local machine and when its working i want to implement on web server. The the php script will be running in /var/www folder and the .wav files will be in /srv/ftp/.../ so i have to make a relative path like ../../../srv/ftp/... ?

Comment: I am not really getting why *"testing on local machine"* can be accepted as excuse of doing things wrong way. I will try to edit my answer to give you better fishing pole

Comment: I understand what you are saying, i'll try both ways and sees what its best for my needs.
Thanks for the help

Comment: the ../ doesnt work any idea why? It seems that the "../" part of the relative path is just ignored. I searched alternatives to ../ besides    writing the absolute path and everyone says to use ../

Comment: @JorgeSilva One big problem you have is that the `/srv/ftp` folder is almost certainly not visible to a web client - unless you've specifically granted the web server permissions to that folder (are you _really_ sure you want to?). Perhaps you could create a symbolic link beneath the web root pointing at the ftp folder. Make sure you're not exposing more through your website than you intended to.

Comment: @Basic  i'll go ahead with the symbolic links idea. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are complicating too much I think. I'd rather reconfigure `ftp` (user?) and make its home withing aboive DocumentRoot **subfolder** instead

Comment: Best way i found to fix my problem was using webmin and create an alias to the directory where the audios are. Then i simply use that alias on the link and  it plays the audio just fine.